# Нет прав при сохранении файла из UWP приложения

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Пользуюсь стандартной загрузкой файлов через WebClient в любую папку на ПК, получаю ошибку о Unauthorized:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Access to the path 'D:\new.jpg'
>   is denied."

Какие еще может права необходимо дать приложению или какие еще существуют способы что бы скачать файл?

**UPD**

Падает на этапе using (Stream fs = new FileStream

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var data = wc.DownloadData(inputURL);

        using (Stream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\new.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                bw.Write(0xff);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Лучше приведите полный текст ошибки. Вероятно, речь идёт о 401 ошибке - о том, что сайт требует авторизацию (по логину+паролю или другим способом). В этом случае нужно модифицировать код, добавляя авторизацию - иначе скачивать можно будет только с сайтов без авторизации. Приведите ваш код и покажите url сайта с которого вы пытаетесь качать файл.

Comment: @AK нет, именно внутренняя ошибка авторизации записи. Вот ошибка. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Access to the path 'D:\new.jpg' is denied.", код добавил в вопрос

Comment: Тогда это вопрос не о загрузке, а  о сохранении файла и о том, что у вас нет прав писать в эту папку. Ничего так, что в корень диска могут писать только администраторы? Вариантов два: требовать, чтобы приложение запрашивало права побольше, ещё побольше, на всякий случай, чтобы можно было сохранить куда угодно - и это плохой вариант. Либо использовать временные папки, чтобы сохранить/записать файл. А если нет прав на эту папку - то выкидывать исключению пользователю.

Comment: @AK я пробовал писать во все папки, это просто пример, какие еще права надо дать приложению что бы была такая возможность? Писать в любую указанную папку

Comment: Ну тогда нужно ответить на два вопроса. Какими правами обладает учётная запись, от которой запускается код? Какие права доступа выставлены на папку? Допустим, вы хотите записать файл в C:\Temp, покажите права на эту папку. Может у вас приложение крутится не в приложении, а в фоновой службе ОС windows, допустим, вы при установке винды поменяли все дефолтные настройки так, что от них ничего стандартного не осталось.

Comment: @AK да по идее любая учетка может иметь данные свойства, я беру на примере известных уже приложений (Skype, Telegram) у них есть выбор записи в любую папку на ПК при скачивании файлов

Answer (score 2):

> Access to the path 'D:\new.jpg' is denied

UWP по умолчанию имеет довольно ограниченный доступ к файловой системе. Писать в произвольную папку здесь просто так не получится.

В "родные" папки приложения можно писать спокойно. Насчёт всего остального. В зависимости от того, куда Вы собираетесь писать файлы, нужно объявлять соответствующие разрешения через манифест. Подробнее можно посмотреть в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/get-started/fileio-learning-track#access-the-file-system).

Comment: Ну скайп, тг, например может писать загружаемые файлы в любые папки без запросов на то куда он будет это записывать. В манифесте я так понимаю, нужно проставлять все что нужно мне для использования. Может есть все таки вариант по проще?

Comment: К сожалению нет.

Comment: Добавил все возможные "Возможности" в манифесте, все так же. Перенес код из RuntimeComponent в основное приложение, все так же. Этот способ не работает

Comment: Учётка,, под которой запускается код, имеет нужные права?

Comment: Да, пробовал и под админом